# Beta+ Decay the Mass Missing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, radiation

I am confused with such a question:

> What is energy released in beta+ decay ${^{36}_{20}Ca} \rightarrow {^{36}_{19}K} + {^{0}_{1}e}$

I have a question when I was getting the mass difference. Since I know the beta+ decay happens inside the nucleus, so the mass decay is m(Ca) - (m(K) + m(e)). However, the right answer is m(Ca) - (m(K) + **2** m(e)), I am struggled a long time and still don't know where is this 2 from. Can somebody inspires me?

Answer (score 1):

The reaction would be better expressed as

${^{36}_{20}Ca} \rightarrow {^{36}_{19}K} + \beta^+$

So potassium atom with an atomic number of 19 has one less electron than the calcium atom with atomic number 20, and the the calcium nucleus emits a positron in the nuclear reaction.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the balance it helps to decompose the atoms
into nuclei and electrons:

$$ \underbrace{^{36}_{20}Ca^{20+} + 20\ ^{\;\;0}_{-1}e^-}_{^{36}_{20}Ca} \to
  \underbrace{^{36}_{19}K^{19+} + 19\ ^{\;\;0}_{-1}e^-}_{^{36}_{19}K}
  +\ ^{\;\;0}_{-1}e^- +\ ^0_1e^+ $$

Now we see better: in addition to the electrons bound to the $K$ atom,
there is one electron and one positron.